# Difference between --fileds-terminated-by & --input-fields-terminated-by in sqoop hive commands

Tags: hive, sqoop

Can anyone tell what is the difference b/w these 2 arguments   --fileds-terminated-by & --input-fields-terminated-by in sqoop ? & when to use the same with an example

Answer (score 7):

**--fields-terminated-by** is the option used during Sqoop Import (ie. they are the Output Formatting arguments) which describe how the data will be written to HDFS.

**--input-fields-terminated-by** is the option used during Sqoop Export (ie. they are Input Formatting arguments) which describe how the input data is present in HDFS before exporting to RDBMS.

Reference: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html

Answer (score -1):

In Hive, It will be like

**row format delimited**

**fields terminated by ','**

This tells how the columns are separated in input data.